# Position fixed but scrolls with the screen

Tags: css, position, fixed

I've been racking my brain on this and I can't seem to get it to behave the way I want to. Essentially, I want the element which contains the `open` and `close` buttons to remain fixed even when I've already opened the navigation.

Right now, what happens is after clicking `#open`, the container scrolls with the screen. I want it to emulate the behavior similar to when I haven't cliked `#open` yet (meaning the said container remains fixed in position).

Thanks everyone! Code provided below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <title>Rotating Navigation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="circle-container">
                <div class="circle">
                    <button id="close">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button id="open">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars"> </i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Amazing Article</h1>
                <small>Florin Pop</small>
                <p
                    >Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora,
                    nihil nisi! Aut, deleniti consectetur ratione consequatur, rerum
                    dolorum, ipsa debitis nulla ut autem maiores architecto quos quia amet
                    sapiente labore. Ex ipsam minima quam accusamus, perferendis illum
                    rerum numquam repellendus recusandae sed quas. Aperiam quisquam animi
                    commodi excepturi, at magni, in assumenda veniam impedit iusto,
                    molestiae dolores consectetur tenetur non fugit sapiente beatae eius
                    praesentium consequatur! Maxime magnam ipsam laborum expedita totam
                    nihil magni similique ratione sequi mollitia tempore voluptate dolorum
                    dolorem, quisquam quasi explicabo dolores natus temporibus
                    necessitatibus rerum praesentium perspiciatis nesciunt modi harum!
                    Perspiciatis amet modi eveniet doloremque?</p
                >
                <h3>My Dog</h3>
                <img src="./assets/charles-deluvio-Mv9hjnEUHR4-unsplash.jpg" alt="" />
                <p
                    >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt
                    explicabo ipsum quaerat debitis sapiente cum ratione perspiciatis
                    dolore, odio impedit necessitatibus eligendi facilis obcaecati
                    temporibus expedita repudiandae harum incidunt, enim perferendis
                    cupiditate distinctio! Earum optio accusantium quos qui et
                    perspiciatis ullam odio error modi voluptas quidem, itaque quisquam
                    labore minima. Tenetur libero distinctio sit animi iusto dolore
                    adipisci quam dolorum ea blanditiis pariatur perferendis, ullam
                    aliquid, qui voluptates id facilis inventore quibusdam minus quia.
                    Eveniet!</p
                >
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>About</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap");

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #222;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 50px;
}

.container.show-nav {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.circle-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
}

.circle {
    background-color: #ff7979;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}

.container.show-nav .circle {
    transform: rotate(-80deg);
    position: fixed;
}

.circle button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
}

.circle button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.circle button#open {
    left: 60%;
}

.circle button#close {
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.container.show-nav + nav li {
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

nav ul li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 40px 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
}

nav ul li i {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transform: translateX(-150%);
}

nav ul li + li {
    margin-left: 15px;
    transform: translateX(-200%);
}

nav ul li + li + li {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.content img {
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.content h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.conent small {
    color: #555;
    font-style: italic;
}

.content p {
    color: #333;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```js
const open = document.getElementById("open");
const close = document.getElementById("close");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

open.addEventListener("click", () => container.classList.add("show-nav"));

close.addEventListener("click", () => container.classList.remove("show-nav"));
```

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet which demonstrates the problem? The code you provided is  not complete so I can't see the buttons

Comment: Hi. Does this work for you? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rram003/cdf2bL1n/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull out the `circle-container` and everything in it from the `container`.  Once it is separate you can position it to be fixed to the top left corner of the body and won't be bound by the same rules as if it was inside `container` Then you can style it from there.

I changed quite a few things in this code to get it to work so look it over and see what I did.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/708Lo31v/

```js
const open = document.getElementById("open");
const close = document.getElementById("close");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const cont1 = document.querySelector(".circle-container");


open.addEventListener("click", () => container.classList.add("show-nav"));
open.addEventListener("click", () => cont1.classList.add("show-nav"));

close.addEventListener("click", () => container.classList.remove("show-nav"));
close.addEventListener("click", () => cont1.classList.remove("show-nav"));
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap");

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #222;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 50px;
 
}

.container.show-nav {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    position: relative;
}



.circle-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.circle {
    background-color: #ff7979;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}

.circle-container.show-nav .circle {
    transform: rotate(-100deg);
    position: fixed;
}

.circle button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
}

.circle button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.circle button#open {
    left: 60%;
}

.circle button#close {
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.container.show-nav + nav li {
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

nav ul li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 40px 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
}

nav ul li i {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transform: translateX(-150%);
}

nav ul li + li {
    margin-left: 15px;
    transform: translateX(-200%);
}

nav ul li + li + li {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.content img {
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.content h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.conent small {
    color: #555;
    font-style: italic;
}

.content p {
    color: #333;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <title>Rotating Navigation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
  
    <div class="circle-container">
                <div class="circle">
                    <button id="close">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button id="open">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars"> </i>
                    </button>
                </div>
          </div>

          
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Amazing Article</h1>
                <small>Florin Pop</small>
                <p
                    >Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora,
                    nihil nisi! Aut, deleniti consectetur ratione consequatur, rerum
                    dolorum, ipsa debitis nulla ut autem maiores architecto quos quia amet
                    sapiente labore. Ex ipsam minima quam accusamus, perferendis illum
                    rerum numquam repellendus recusandae sed quas. Aperiam quisquam animi
                    commodi excepturi, at magni, in assumenda veniam impedit iusto,
                    molestiae dolores consectetur tenetur non fugit sapiente beatae eius
                    praesentium consequatur! Maxime magnam ipsam laborum expedita totam
                    nihil magni similique ratione sequi mollitia tempore voluptate dolorum
                    dolorem, quisquam quasi explicabo dolores natus temporibus
                    necessitatibus rerum praesentium perspiciatis nesciunt modi harum!
                    Perspiciatis amet modi eveniet doloremque?</p
                >
                <h3>My Dog</h3>
                <img src="./assets/charles-deluvio-Mv9hjnEUHR4-unsplash.jpg" alt="" />
                <p
                    >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt
                    explicabo ipsum quaerat debitis sapiente cum ratione perspiciatis
                    dolore, odio impedit necessitatibus eligendi facilis obcaecati
                    temporibus expedita repudiandae harum incidunt, enim perferendis
                    cupiditate distinctio! Earum optio accusantium quos qui et
                    perspiciatis ullam odio error modi voluptas quidem, itaque quisquam
                    labore minima. Tenetur libero distinctio sit animi iusto dolore
                    adipisci quam dolorum ea blanditiis pariatur perferendis, ullam
                    aliquid, qui voluptates id facilis inventore quibusdam minus quia.
                    Eveniet!</p
                >
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>About</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So thankful for this! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @jecrram No problem.  Please consider making this as the answer if it solved your problem.